# Validar si ya existe un valor en la base de datos PDO

Tags: php, html

soy algo nuevo en esto y estoy tratando de hacer una de mis primeras páginas y he llegado a este pequeño inconveniente que seguro debe de ser facil de resolver jajaja
En fin, estoy creando usuarios y no quiero que se repitan el username ni el email. Como puedo comprobar que ya existen en mi base de datos y en caso de que sea así que salte un mensaje de alerta de que el usuario o el mail ya existe?
Este es el código

```
<?php
require 'database.php';

  if (!empty($_POST['fullname']) && !empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (fullname, username, email,password, tipo, puntaje) VALUES (:fullname, :username, :email, :password, 0, 0)";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':fullname', $_POST['fullname']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':username', $_POST['username']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email']);
    $password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':password', $password);
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
      header("Location: /login.php");
    } else {
      $message = 'Ingreso invalido';
    }
  }
?>
```

Desde ya gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creas un metodo check que haga un select

```
$sql = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username=:username and email=:email";
```

Si esto te devuelve una fila quiere decir que ya existe.
La otra opcion que tienes es generar un UK (unique key o clave unica) en la base de datos entonces cuando intentes ingresar te devolvera que ya existe por un error sql.

Comment: Gracias! Me ha servido